# Exporting Room database to another folder or directory inst working

Tags: java, database, android-studio, android-sqlite, android-room

I'm trying to export Database file from root directory to download directory. The database is created using Room, everything is working perfectly, i can add data, delete and update data , but when i try to export database it gives exception
***java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/storage/emulated/0/Download: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory***)

[Screen shot while debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otD5V.png)

i am using following lines of code to export db.

private void exportDB() {

```
    try {
        File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
        boolean ans = sd.canWrite();
        //if (ans) {

        String currentDBPath ="/data/" + getPackageName() + "/databases/" + SAMPLE_DB_NAME + "";
        String backupDBPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/";
        File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
        File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

        if (currentDB.exists()) {
            FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
            FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
            dst.transferFrom(src, 1, src.size());
            src.close();
            dst.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("MYAPP", "exception", e);

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Please have a look at this and guide me, Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
String backupDBPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/" + SAMPLE_DB_NAME;
```

and to be sure that the Download directory exists follow `File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);`

with

```
backupDB.getParentFile().mkDirs();
```

- This assumes that you want the backup file name to be the same as the database file name. If not then you may wish to use something other than SAMPLE_DB_NAME.

**Edit**

If the above still fails then you are not providing the required permissions. You need to refer to https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/

As an example here's a slightly modified version of your code:-

```
private void exportDB() {

    /* get an alternative backup location where permissions exist */
    File bkp = new File( MainActivity.this.getDatabasePath("x").getParent() + File.separator + "backups" + File.separator + "bkp_" + SAMPLE_DB_NAME);

    try {
        File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
        boolean ans = sd.canWrite();


        String currentDBPath = "/data/" + getPackageName() + "/databases/" + SAMPLE_DB_NAME + "";
        String backupDBPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/";
        File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
        /* requires permissions */
        File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);
        backupDB.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        /* uses ....databases/backups directory */
        bkp.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        backupDB = bkp;

        if (currentDB.exists()) {
            FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
            FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
            dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size()); //<<<<< 0 not 1
            src.close();
            dst.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("MYAPP", "exception", e);

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

As can be seen this now backs up the database (sla_database) file :-

[image]

**Warning**

Unless you have specifically forced [Journal mode](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/RoomDatabase.JournalMode) then you need to consider the files as outlined in red above.

You can see that the database file backed up is 4k. Yet the -wal file and -shm file are both quite a bit larger. The -wal file contains changes to the database that are waiting to be applied (checkpointed).

So you either need to backup the -wal -shm files as well or fully checkpoint the database (closing the database will fully checkpoint the database). see https://sqlite.org/wal.html

Comment: didnt work, still same exception

Comment: @MuhammadAsad. see the edited answer.

Comment: sir it worked but the new bkp_ file does not contain any data inside , but original file has data inside,secondly the problem is still the same with this method , that we can not access by the user on there phone

Comment: Actually the main purpose of doing this, my client need that database file , they have there script that generate bills automatically,

Comment: @MuhammadAsad you need to read and digest the the answer.

Comment: hello Sir! i have gone through the complete documentation or read and write permission, and i figured out the permission problem in andorid11,
Sir i am still getting an IO exception   **open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)** even though files and directories exists.